# Is there a way to retrieve an object's id in TEST mode given the same object in LIVE mode (with different id)?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Specifically, assume there are two `Price` objects that share the same attributes (except for the `id`), one in the TEST and the other in the LIVE mode. Is there a way to retrieve the object's `id` in TEST mode once I have the object in LIVE mode?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to achieve this. But you could use the [`metadata`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-metadata) property of the live mode Price object to store the ID of the test mode Price object.

Note that you will need the livemode API keys to retrieve the livemode Price object and the testmode API keys to retrieve the testmode Price object.